# small brushed motors thrust

Tags: dc-motor, quad-copter

I built a quadcopter. It had a very low total thrust/weight ratio, and after I added some components it doesn't fly any more, so I want to change its motors and propellers in order to increase thrust.

The total weight is around 90g; of this, 26g are the motors (20mm brushed motors).

Is it possible to generate [64 + motor weight]g of thrust with 4 brushed motors, each with a small propeller?
If it's possible, what kind of brushed motors and propellers should I use?

Here are my actual motors/propellers; I don't have technical data about them because I don't remember where they come from (I have the since a very long time).
Looking around on Google I found those images; in the motor image's [site](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/mini-quad-brushed-motor-8-5x20mm-4-pack.html) I found some information, but not very precise...

[image]

Comment: "I want to make my car faster.  I dont know what kind of car it is, but it has 4 wheels and makes a vroom noise.  What should I put on it?"  You need datasheets, man.  Sorry China is bad about providing them, but you won't get any real answers without them.  I'm guessing somebody will vote to close because of that.

Comment: @insta "I want to make my car faster. The only thing I know about my car is that it has 4 wheels..., because the car seller didn't gave me any technical data booklet and I don't have any experience in car building. But I'm interested in cars, so I want to learn enough to make it go faster rather than buying a faster one on giving it to someone else to do the job for me. So I go to my friend, who is a car mechanic, and I ask some questions, sure that he will give me useful information. If he can't understand what kind of wheels I have, and if they can go faster, he'll give me some other wheels"

Comment: @insta maybe my question is to be closed, but not because I don't know data which isn't really needed to answer, neither because I don't know the answer to my own question. "Is it possible to generate [64 + motor weight]g of thrust with 4 brushed motors, each with a small propeller? If it's possible, what kind of brushed motors and propellers should I use?" is maybe too vague, but has nothing to do with Chinese datasheets.

Comment: Apparently the major manufacturers have thrust tables: http://www.dronetrest.com/t/how-to-choose-the-right-motor-for-your-multicopter-drone/568 and you can calculate the optimum propellor speed: https://quadcopterproject.wordpress.com/propeller-and-motor-selection/

Comment: Quadcopters fly, so it must be possible. The data is out there.

Comment: @Neil_UK quadcopters fly, but the most have brushless motors, only the smallest have brushed

Comment: 90g thrust will not fly a 90g copter. You need  at least 1.5:1 thrust/weight for good control. Hobbyking reviewer:- "I estimate them to be 12-14000KV. They draw approximately 1.8 amps each @ 4vdc with the Hubsan X4 props... I prefer the Hubsan props over the HK orange and grey props as they seem to be too much load for the HK motor."  How much current do _your_ motors draw? What is the battery voltage under load? What propellers are you using? Measure the DC resistance of each motor, what do you get?

Comment: I measured what I was able to: my motors draw 1.5A each (I measured a single motor, with the other disconnected from the battery, because my multimeter couldn't measure the current flowing from the battery with 4 motors connected). Using a lipo battery charged at 3.7V the under load voltage was around 3.3V. Measuring the resistance between one motor's terminals when it's unpowered I get something around 0.4-0.5Ω. I really don't know how to find out what my propellers are, I'm sorry.

Comment: If you don't have technical data, make some. Measure the speed and thrust of the motor/propeller combination at different voltages and currents. Learn how motor power and efficiency vary with speed, voltage and current. Ditto for propellors, how thrust and power vary with speed, diameter and pitch. Maybe once you learn the science you can find a propellor size and pitch that'll produce the thrust you need from those motors. Or maybe you'll learn what you need in a motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking for spare motors for existing quadrotors and back-calculating from here. Here is one example:

- Google for "quadcopter dc motor"
- First link: http://www.robotshop.com/en/crazyflie-20-mini-quadcopter-motor.html
- Corresponding quadrotor: http://www.robotshop.com/en/crazyflie-20-mini-quadcopter.html
- Notice motor weight: 2.7 gramm and whole copter: 27 g + 15g payload
- This means total trust is 31g + motors' weight

So these motors do not work. Search for the next motor and repeat the exercise. Keep the notes in spreadsheet or a text file. If you checked 30 motors and none of them worked it is time to give up.